# Firebase Remote Config A/B testing - Error in iOS experiment console

Tags: ios, firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to get an A/B test with Remote Config up and running and I'm having some trouble with the iOS part. After setting the experiment up as described in the documentation it doesn't seem to work. For all iOS versions I've tried I'm always receiving the default remote config value (I tried it by deleting and reinstalling the app several times).

A few days have past and now I'm seeing the following error in the firebase console for that experiment:

[image]

Any ideas why this could be happening?

I did exactly the same thing with android as well and it works just fine. When I just change the default remote config values it get's updated properly on both platfoms, so I'm assuming the remote config setup is done correctly, am I right?

I also wasn't able to see the variant value at the iOS device which I've added to the managed test devices with the instance id token.

Comment: any luck with that?

Comment: well, not really unfortunately...I cancelled this experiment and did setup a similar one maybe a week later and this one worked as expected, so I assumed it was a bug in the firebase console.

Answer (score 2):

For me, in the `Goals` section, I removed one of the `Additional metrics to track` which I manually added and then it worked correctly.

**EDIT:**

You can not add your `Activation event` as a metric in your `Goals`.

Answer (score 0):

clear activation event and make sure to add valid event for goals if custom event